# How can I run two instances of a rails app from 2 different git branches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I need to run two rails server instances on the same machine on different ports from two different git branches of the same repo. One will be in production mode, the other staging. This is a temporary solution for QA to have a separate staging app while we set up a proper staging server.

I know how to run different rails servers on different ports from the same git branch, but I can't think of a way to run from two different git branches that doesn't involve cloning the git repo twice.

So this may be more of a git question. As far as I know only one git branch can be "active" at once.

Is there a git-based option to have two active branches in two directories or something like that. Or some other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Ideally, you would have 2 separate servers, one for production with optimal resources (storage, CPU, RAM, bandwidth, uptime, etc), and one for staging with the minimum required. If you can't do this for some reason, you could have 2 different folders on the same server and use one for production and the other for staging.

Comment: @MrYoshiji the question is about how best to do this with git. Are you suggesting I make a separate copy of the app dir outside of git? A separate clone of the git repo checked out to a different branch?

Comment: If you are using docker, it makes easier.

Comment: @pixelearth you can achieve this by `git worktree`, Please checkout this https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay I think this is the right answer. I found this on my own earlier today, but if you put this suggestion in the form of an answer, I'll accept it. Might want to throw in a command or two for good measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm describing my comment here as answer.

You can achieve this by `git worktree`. as worktree allowing you to check out more than one branch at a time.

`git worktree add --track -b <branch> <path> <remote>/<branch>
 git worktree remove [-f] <worktree>`

Ex. if you want to add any new tree at any point like.

`git worktree add -b emergency-fix ../temp master`

and remove at any point with

`git worktree remove ../temp`.

Please check [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Capistrano/Passenger/Nginx to run multiple rails instances in the same server from two different git branches.

The configuration is a bit long, so I created a blog post [here](https://medium.com/@lalusaud_84531/deploy-staging-and-production-applications-to-single-server-using-capistrano-rails-1d5ab558d44f) with instructions.

The only difference from your requirement is I didn't use different ports, instead I used different sub-domains for staging and production environment. For eg:

```
http://staging.[your-domain].com
http://production.[your-domain].com
```

This may not be exact answer what you are looking for as it takes slightly different approach. However I think it serves a similar purpose.